# Use Solver in a JS applications

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, solver

I need to rewrite Solver function from Excel VBA modul to JS application.

In Excel it is defined like this:

```html
SolverOk SetCell:="$H$15", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$17"
    SolverSolve True
```

I found this library to use Solver in JS, https://github.com/Zolmeister/js-solver but not sure how to write Excel like equation.

Please help if someone has a clue. I'm not familiar with Solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel solver is a mask to a group of optimization techniques, some linear, andsome not. This solver that you found does not do the same as Excel Solver. You should try to find some Linear Programming Libraries, or Optimization libraries. It will depend on the type of problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This is code that is currently in VBA, and witch I try to rewrite in JS using some libraries. But I'm not so familiar with it. Do you have some library to sugest?

Comment: Not all code will show on VBA. Lots of functions in VBA have their source code not available, so when you call a function like solver, there is an algorithm behind it that you won't be able to see.
Try this, maybe it will help you 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-lp-solver